# Cloud Scheduler - Terrafrom - How to pass current date in CloudSheduler body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-scheduler

Am using cloudScheduler to schedule the dataflow job. Where i need to pass the rundate/runtime/current date dynamically to dataflow job using cloudsheduler body.
Am reading the body parameters using Java Options in Dataflow job code.

Looking for syntax to read header **X-CloudScheduler-ScheduleTime** in cloudschduler body

body = base64encode(<<-EOT
{
"jobName": "${each.value.name}_${http_target.h}",
"parameters": {
"bigtableInstanceId": "${var.cloudscheduler_bigtable_instanceid}",
"bigtableProjectId": "${var.project_id}",
"bigtableTableId": "${each.value.bigtableTableId}",
"inputFilePattern": "${each.value.inputFilePattern}",
**"runningdate" :????????**
"region": "${var.cloudscheduler_region}",
},
"environment": {
"numWorkers": "2",
"tempLocation": "gs://gcslocation/temp2",
"zone": "${var.cloudscheduler_region}-a"
}
}
EOT
)
}

How to pass the scheduled date/rundate in the body **"runningdate" :????????**  of cloudscheduler which we read in dataflow job code.

Answer (score 1):

(Simple Approach) Try using [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-python) rather than [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler).

Cloud Scheduler is supposed work like a unix cron job, to schedule and run jobs.

Cloud Functions are mainly useful for uses cases where arguments need to be parsed & dynamic decision to be made like should I run Dataflow job or any as such.

If you have requirement/such use case to use `Cloud Scheduler`, then what you can do is

- Use **Cloud Functions** to record your arguments and store in commonly accessible locations like DB or Bucket
- Use **Cloud Scheduler** to do the required step after that.

If I misunderstood, your question, please do elaborate with more details & examples.

Comment: I have update the question bit brief. Am using scheduler to sheduler dataflow jobs. And my dataflow job code needs to rundata/scheduled date where i need to look for the files landed on that day